# How to get First in and Last out in multiple records also with night shift

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I have this query Getting all time in and time out without having a multiple records but i have encountered multiple records which I'm having a problem how do i delete those multiple record

```
with 
cte1 as ( select *, 
                 coalesce(lag(verify_state) over (partition by user_id order by verify_date asc),1) prev_state,
                 coalesce(lead(verify_state) over (partition by user_id order by verify_date asc),0) next_state
          from tbl_excel_attendance
),
cte2 as ( select *, 
                 lead(verify_date) over (partition by user_id order by verify_date asc) next_date
          from cte1 
          where (prev_state,verify_state,next_state) in ( (1,0,0),(1,0,1), (0,1,0) )
)
select * 
from cte2 
where verify_state = 0
  and next_date is not null
order by 2,3
```

See this [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a1c2dcfd2b5d88d79deef83bbba469d1) for example.
The user_id of 14 and his attendance of 2019/11/11 is problem and has a multiple records. how do i delete those multiple and left the first in and last out.

```
Verify_state stands for 0 = Time In and 1 = Time out
```

Expected output :

```
user_id     verify_date      verify_state  prev_state next_state next_date
     14     2019-11-07 07:25:00     0          1          0     2019-11-07 20:09:00
     14     2019-11-08 07:18:00     0          1          1     2019-11-08 17:38:00
     14     2019-11-11 07:20:00     0          0          1     2019-11-11 20:05:00
```